# why is Hive giving metaexception when i am trying drop database and i am using mysql as metastore?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

```
hive>> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ABC.XYZ;
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:One or
>   more instances could not be retrieved)

### hive-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true://localhost/hive</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**i am using hadoop 2.6.0 with hive 1.1.0 on RHEL6 and mysql version is mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm **

### Detailed log:

```
2015-05-08 02:27:54,644 ERROR [main]: exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:failed(512)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveExcepti
on: MetaException(message:One or more instances could not be retrieved)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:1003)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:934)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTable(DDLTask.java:3719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTableOrPartitions(DDLTask.java:3654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:754)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: MetaException(message:One or more instances could not be retrieved)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore$GetHelper.run(ObjectStore.java:2378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPartitionsInternal(ObjectStore.java:1705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPartitions(ObjectStore.java:1699)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:98)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getPartitions(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.dropPartitionsAndGetLocations(HiveMetaStore.java:1632)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:16
76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.drop_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.drop_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1
974)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.drop_table_with_environment_context(SessionHiveMetaSt
oreClient.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.dropTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.dropTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:842)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:91)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.dropTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:997)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: you wrote *when i am trying drop database* but you didn't post any code fragment where you really try to do that

Comment: Remove `://localhost/hive` from `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` property.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, It was typo. I checked, it is not there in actual hive-site.xml.

Comment: @Alex: Hi Alex, i did on top

Answer (score 0):

Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar and copy that jar into hive library file.
It worked for me.